# How do I refer to NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users on non English systems?

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows

I have a script that grants permission to assemblies in a DB, but the execution fails on this saying that NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users doesn't exists.

This is a non English system.

Comment: What does your script look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine little bobby and David's answers:

On an english system, get the SID of the account you want:

```
  select suser_sid('NT AUTHORITY\authenticated users')
```

In code use this sid to obtain the local name:

```
 select suser_sname(0x01010000000000050B000000)
```

Between these two you can obtain the name and build a dynamic SQL to grant the permission you want.

Comment: Not all SIDs are meaningful on different machines. Certainly the well-known ones are. In which case why you you ever look up `'NT AUTHORITY\authenticated users'`? You'd always use the well-known SID. Surely?

Comment: @David: you need to lookup (at least once) the well known sid to get the SQL Server varbinary representation.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the appropriate [well-known security identifier](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243330). In your case it is:

```
SID: S-1-5-11
Name: Authenticated Users
```